# Autosize height of ggplotly in shiny

Tags: shiny, plotly

I have a very high `plotlyOutput` (because it has many categories on the y axis). If It's rendered just with `ggplotly(g)`, I get this plot, with a fixed height: 
[image: Very short plot]

So I specify it's `height`, like this: `ggplotly(g, height = 1500)`, I get an appropiate size (the following is a fraction of the plot because of it's size):
[image]

My problem is that when I filter the data through my app's input controls, It maintains the height (cause its now fixed), even when there are very few categories on the y axis. Like this (the following is a fraction of the plot because of it's size):

[image]

So, ¿how can I get dynamic height for my `plotlyOutput`, such as when there's, say, 3 categories on the y axis, It adjust the `height` to be shorter, but building to a maximum of `1500px` as the number of categories increases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any solution except this one, which calculates the height in function of the number of categories in the plot:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

dat <- data.frame(
  Letter = c(LETTERS,letters),
  height = rpois(52, 10)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxInput("filter", "Filter"),
  plotlyOutput("ggly", height = "100%")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output[["ggly"]] <- renderPlotly({
    ggdat <- if(input[["filter"]]) dat[dat$Letter %in% c("A","B"),] else dat
    height <- nlevels(droplevels(ggdat$Letter)) * 30
    gg <- ggplot(ggdat) + geom_col(aes(x = Letter, y = height)) + coord_flip()
    ggplotly(gg, height = min(1500, max(300, height)))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much... that's a great workaround! if I only could get you 5 upvotes!